# having trouble starting instapy

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, instagram, geckodriver

I am trying to use InstaPy for the first time. I have already installed selenium and geckodriver so that it would work with firefox. I also have firefox installed as well. I am able to launch firefox and go to Instagram and log in using the code below

```
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\users\alvin\Desktop\geckodriver.exe')
    browser.implicitly_wait(5)

    browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

    sleep(2)

    username_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='username']")
    username_input.send_keys("x")
    password_input = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password']")
    password_input.send_keys(("x"))
    login_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit']")
    login_button.click()

    sleep(5)

    browser.close()
```

but, when I am trying to use InstaPy instead, it does not work, using the code below

```
username = 'x'
password = 'x'

session = InstaPy(username=username, password=password)
session.login()
```

I get an error saying: selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Comment: See https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy/issues/4837

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the browser path just like:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

# I used firefox here
browser = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'

session = InstaPy(username='xxxxxxx',
                  password='xxxxxxxx',
                  browser_executable_path=browser)
session.login()
```

This worked to solve the problem for me.

Comment: I literally just cannot thank you enough.